# What are the limits of Conditional Merge Fields in Mass Email?

Tags: massemailmessage, merge

I'm trying to use conditional merge fields in mass emails from salesforce to customise the email based on account characteristics.

The aim is that based on checkboxes I can create a much more personalised email - rather than having to write 5 or 6 (and also have the risk of them overlapping as segmentation isn't precise)

So in the face of SF support telling me it can't be done "We cannot use condition like the one in this scenario in the HTML templates." I've managed to get the following working - albeit the  syntax appears to be `IF(logical_test, value_if_false, value_if_true)` which is the reverse of normal

i.e `{!if(!Account.checkbox__c=true,"Random Text 1","Random Text 2")}`

So what are the limits of formulae in mass email template? Can you nest if statements? what other functions work etc?

Comment: Have you considered Visualforce email templates? They might give you more flexibility.

Comment: I did briefly and for this the learning curve was too steep. I've added it onto my list of things to do ;)

Comment: The `IF` formula isn't the opposite like you have stated in your question.  Your formula has a not operator (`!`) in it: `!Account.checkbox=true`.